# Adding checkboxes to table populated with mysql

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have been searching on this topic and the more I read the more confused I get. I hope you can help me on this.

My objective is to add checkboxes to a table in order to be able to delete the rows I select from that table. So my code til now is like this:

```
if ($arch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, age FROM table WHERE id = ?)) { 
  $arch ->execute(array($id));
  $data = $arch->fetchAll();  
  echo '<div class="coolTable" ><table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Check</td></tr>';
    foreach ($data as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
      foreach ($row as $col){
      $col=nl2br($col);
      echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
      }
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
  echo '</table></div>';
}
```

With this, I have all my checkboxes in place. But now, how can I submit the checkboxes with a `Post` so I can `Delete` the rows I checked?

I suppose I can use an array to name each checkbox? but don`t know how :-s

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550632/create-update-command-at-same-form-with-many-data/20551179#20551179

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox"></td>';
```

with

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="" id="checkbox"></td>';
```

You can access every value of checked checkbox using this array `$_POST['checkbox']` if you are using POST method or `$_GET['checkbox']` for GET method.

PS: You should give your checkbox's a value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but tell me please how do I associate the Id of the row that has been checked, so I can delete it later?

Comment: Put the id as value of your checkbox !